# SQL Server Service Broker and batches

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, messaging, service-broker

Am I right in my understanding of SQL Server (2008 R2 in this case) Service Broker that messages are only batched in terms of conversations? In other words, if I have a query like this:

```
DECLARE @messages TABLE(
     handle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
     message_body NVARCHAR(MAX),
     message_type_name SYSNAME
);

RECEIVE TOP 5
    conversation_handle,
    message_body,
    message_type_name
FROM dbo.MyMessageQueue
INTO @messages

SELECT conversation_handle, message_body FROM @messages
```

that I will only get five rows returned if they are from the same conversation? At the moment I am sending out my messages one conversation at a time, but if there are ten such messages in the queue, then they are only being returned one at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RECEIVE` will dequeue only messages belonging to *one conversation group*. Unless you do explicit conversation group management, each conversation is its own group. If you only send one message per conversation, then you'll end up `RECEIVE`-ing only one message every time. This is covered in [Conversation Group Locks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171615%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

`RECEIVE` is a fairly expensive statement to run, so for high throughput you must group more messages together, usually via [conversation reuse](http://rusanu.com/2007/04/25/reusing-conversations/).